# How to set up sails app to connect to redis cluster?

Tags: sails.js, redis-cluster

We were able to set up our sails app to use redis as our session store and socket connection.  But we don't know how to set up sails to connect to a redis cluster, any thoughts/examples available?

---

Just to make it a little more clear, our sails app is already using redis using a config similar to :

```
host: 'localhost',
port: 6379,
ttl: <redis session TTL in seconds>,
db: 0,
pass: <redis auth password>
prefix: 'sess:'
```

But now we want to set it up to use redis cluster, which might be running on various servers and various ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure app to keep cookies in redis in

`./config/session.js`

configuration file.

**UPD:** To connect to redis cluster you may use another adopter with cluster support. [sails-ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-ioredis) seems to work fine for you (I don't use it by myself though). Details from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088363/connection-to-redis-cluster-failed) may help you as well.

Comment: Added more details in the question, we are looking for solution using redis cluster, not just a single redis instance

Comment: Thanks! Will check that out.